# python icalendar setting dtstart properly

Tags: python, datetime, icalendar, rfc5545

I'm setting up a script to format a bunch of hockey schedules into .ics files, using python and the python package [iCalendar](http://icalendar.readthedocs.org).

When I set:

```
event.add('dtstart', game_datetime[i])
event.add('dtend', game_datetime[i]+timedelta(hours=i))
```

I get the following in the resultant .ics file:

```
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20141019T140500
DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:20141019T160500
```

Clearly not ideal; it appears to be passing over the object and not the value. So when I try and set it using strftime() as following:

```
#event.add('dtstart', game_datetime[i].strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ'))
#event.add('dtend', (game_datetime[i]+timedelta(hours=i)).strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ'))
```

I get the following error:

```
File "D:\schedule_format.py", line 72, in <module>
event.add('dtstart', game_datetime[i].strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ'))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\icalendar-3.9.dev0-py2.7.egg\icalendar\cal.py", line 171, in add
value = self._encode(name, value, parameters, encode)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\icalendar-3.9.dev0-py2.7.egg\icalendar\cal.py", line 123, in _encode
obj = klass(value)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\icalendar-3.9.dev0-py2.7.egg\icalendar\prop.py", line 276, in __init__
raise ValueError('You must use datetime, date, timedelta or time')
ValueError: You must use datetime, date, timedelta or time
```

So clearly I'm supposed to be using a datetime object, but apparently I'm not using it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't know what you have in game_datetime but i faced this problem like you and use like this for date type property and it's work:

```
from time import strftime,gmtime
from icalendar import Calendar,Parameters,Todo
import icalendar
from datetime import *

year = int(strftime("%Y", gmtime()))
month = int(strftime("%m", gmtime()))
day = int(strftime("%d", gmtime()))
hour = int(strftime("%H", gmtime()))
minute = int(strftime("%M", gmtime()))
second = int(strftime("%S", gmtime()))

temp = Todo()
temp.add('CREATED',datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute,second))
```

you should change 'CREATED' to date type you want

Answer (score 2):

You can use vDatetime function of icalendar package on a python datetime object

```
from icalendar import Calendar, Event, vDatetime
event.add('dtstart', vDatetime(starttime))
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are seeing as a problem:

`RFC5545` section 3.3.5 ([link][1]), states:

> Value Name:  DATE-TIME

> Purpose:  This value type is used to identify values that specify a
> precise calendar date and time of day.

> Format Definition:  This value type is defined by the following
> notation:

> ```
>   date-time  = date "T" time ;As specified in the DATE and TIME
> ```

```
                              ;value definitions
```

> [...]
> For example, the following represents January 18, 1998, at
> 11 PM:
> 19980118T230000

Which looks very similar (and quite normally) to what iCalendar generated.

If you have a specific issue, could you clarify the desired output?
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5